# How to fetch city events?

Tags: android, gps, location

I wanted to venture into making apps. I wanted to make an app that gathers the events around the user location wise. I want the app to show the events close to user using the GPS of the phone. There is a city page where all the events are listed but I don't have any ideas how I will be able to fetch the data. What are the other ways I can go forward with this? It would be encouraging so that I can research further.

Comment: what have you done.post the code you tried

Comment: @nikhil I haven't coded anything yet. I was asking if there was any API's for city events besides facebook events.

Comment: http://www.last.fm/api/show/geo.getEvents

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
http://www.last.fm/api/show/geo.getEvents
```

login this and get the api calls and use it in your code

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a combination of api's to give you the data you are looking for, one such provider i found was http://api.eventful.com/, you can probably even try including [foursqaure](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events) and [meetup's](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/events/) api and even facebook opengraph event api can also provide some handy data.